# unable to install libxml-ruby 2.6 on mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Tried:

```
gem install libxml-ruby -v 2.6.0
```

getting the following error

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150608-66572-6mmes4.rb extconf.rb
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>   extconf.rb:17:in `': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.6.0 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.2.0/libxml-ruby-2.6.0/gem_make.out